# What does a healthy CNAME to an S3 web access bucket look like?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-s3

I have `feed.foodschmood.com` configured according to Amazon's instructions (a CNAME to one of their endpoints, which is itself a CNAME), but I'm skeptical that this is a "proper" configuration. Admittedly, things do seem to work. I get some warning signs, though. All the automated DNS checkers report errors with it.

E.g., [Pingdom reports](http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/?domain=feed.foodschmood.com), **"Delegation not found at parent. No delegation could be found at the parent, making your zone unreachable from the Internet."**

Is this normal? Or is there a problem? "Parent" can mean a couple different things in DNS, and this is a little beyond my experience. My DNS configuration is very simple:

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;feed.foodschmood.com.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
feed.foodschmood.com.   86400   IN  CNAME   feed.foodschmood.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com.  
feed.foodschmood.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com. 60 IN CNAME s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com.  
s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com. 60 IN A 54.231.160.27
```

I manage my DNS using Linode's service, and it's always been solid and error-free. The root domain, `foodschmood.com`, is an A record.

Comment: I took a look at the output of `dig +trace +additional feed.feedschmood.com` and everything looks good to me. This is a Pingdom specific error scenario, and Håkan's answer in the linked question is the same conclusion as mine.

Comment: @AndrewB Thank you so much – I appreciate the help.